# Soft input layout doesn't change as intended

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a problem with my android soft input layout.

What I need is a phone layout which only accepts numeric values.
I have done this before by modifying xml:

```
android:inputType="phone"
android:digits="0123456789"
```

and it worked like a charm.

Now the current EditText is generated dynamically, and I have to do it programmatically.

I've already tried

```
mEditTextET.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED);
mEditTextET.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789"));
```

but it shows text layout instead of phone layout.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use android:inputType ="number"

Comment: _I have to do it programmatically._

Comment: check answer i posted

Answer (score 0):

```
    mEditTextET.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);          
    mEditTextET.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);           
    mEditTextET.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance(false,true));
```

Comment: can you please shed some details on what you've done and why? it will for sure help the author of the question to better understand the suggested solution. regards

Comment: Your solution would pop up the text layout

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.Hope it will solve your problem only `setInputType` like this in your `EditText`

```
mEditTextET.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE);
mEditTextET.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789"));
```

**Device s4 Os : 4.4.2**
[image: **Device s4 Os : 4.4.2**]

Comment: This does show the phone layout, but I can still enter '*' and "#" values.

Comment: some special phn no can contains `*` and `#`. If u don't want that see the Edit

Comment: In my case this won't be a phone number, I just want to use this layout for aesthetic purpose.

Comment: then what u want ? coz in question u asked about `phone kbd layout`

Comment: "What I need is a phone layout which only accepts numeric values". That means - no asterisks or hashtags